# AWS CodeBuild not pausing on breakpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Using steps provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), I kicked off a CodeBuild with the following advanced options checked:

- Enable session connection
- Allow AWS CodeBuild to modify this service role so it can be used with this build project

The buildspec included a codebuild-breakpoint:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - ls -al
      - codebuild-breakpoint
      - cd "${SERVICE_NAME}"
      - ls -al
      - $(aws ecr get-login)
      - TAG="$SERVICE_NAME"
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build --tag "${REPOSITORY_URI}:${TAG}" .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push "${REPOSITORY_URI}:${TAG}"
      - printf '{"tag":"%s"}' $TAG > ../build.json
artifacts:
  files: build.json
```

The build started and produced the following logs **without pausing**:

```
[Container] 2022/02/28 13:49:03 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2022/02/28 13:49:03 Running command ls -al
total 148
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Feb 28 13:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 13:49 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1818 Feb 28 10:54 user-manager\Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   140 Feb 28 10:34 user-manager\body.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     0 Feb 28 10:54 user-manager\shared-modules\
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  4822 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\config-helper\config.js
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  2125 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\config-helper\config\default.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   366 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\config-helper\package.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  9713 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\dynamodb-helper\dynamodb-helper.js
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   399 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\dynamodb-helper\package.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   451 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\token-manager\package.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 13885 Feb 21 14:52 user-manager\shared-modules\token-manager\token-manager.js
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 44372 Feb 28 10:34 user-manager\src\cognito-user.js
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   706 Feb 28 10:34 user-manager\src\package.json
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 32734 Feb 28 10:34 user-manager\src\server.js

[Container] 2022/02/28 13:49:03 Running command codebuild-breakpoint
2022/02/28 13:49:03 Build is paused temporarily and you can use codebuild-resume command in the session to resume this build

[Container] 2022/02/28 13:49:03 Running command cd "${SERVICE_NAME}"
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to user-manager
```

**My primary question is:**  Why didn't the build pause and session manager link become available?

**Side-quest:**  The reason I'm trying to debug the session is to try to determine why the process can't CD to the `user-manager` folder (which clearly exists).  Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure you want cd "${SERVICE_NAME}" or more like cd $"${SERVICE_NAME}" or even cd $SERVICE_NAME?

Comment: @TimBassett I think it should be ok.  That's the way it was in the original version (that worked at some point): https://github.com/mjzone/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/templates/deployment-pipeline-test.template#L138

...and you can see from the following line that it's resolving to `cd to user-manager` (via an environment variable)

Comment: Shot in the dark here, the filenames have a backslash, not a forward slash.  Is that unusual?  Is it possible you have a file named "user-manager\Dockerfile" and not a directory named "user-manager" with a file named "Dockerfile"?

Comment: @TimBassett - Looking at the templates it just grabs this file:
https://github.com/mjzone/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/app/packages/user-manager/user-manager.zip

Comment: @TimBassett - you're right!  They are files!!  I also figured out the issue behind the breakpoint.  I'll add an answer now...

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** The image on the build machine was too old.

**Main quest**

The [template](https://github.com/mjzone/saas-identity-cognito/blob/8d5647dbe8eabd02b60b9c564fcd3e4ab604957e/templates/deployment-pipeline-test.template#L197) specified `aws/codebuild/ubuntu-base:14.04` as the CodeBuild image.  Presumably that image pre-dated the Session Manager functionality (which requires a specific version of the SSM agent to be installed).

I update the agent to `aws/codebuild/standard:5.0` and was able to successfully pause on the breakpoint and connect to the session.

**Side quest**

Once I connected I was able to investigate the cause of the inability to CD to the folder.  I can confirm that Tim's [shot in the dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296278/aws-codebuild-not-pausing-on-breakpoint?noredirect=1#comment126045708_71296278) was correct!  All the entries were in fact files - no folders.

This QuickStart is the gift that keeps on giving!  When/if I get all the issues resolved I'll submit a PR to update the project.  Those interested in the cause of the file/folder issue can follow up there.

**Side quest update**
The strange flattening behaviour was due to creating the zip file on a Windows machine and unzipping it on a unix machine (the build agent uses an Ubuntu image). Just zipped it using 7-Zip and that did the job.